# Comparing different types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm trying to check for equality in a haskell application, which takes in an xs of type [a], as so:

```
myCompare :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> Int
myCompare pointer x xs = if pointer < length xs
                         then if xs !! pointer == xs !! (pointer+1)
                         ....
```

However, Haskell has run into an issue where it cannot carry out a comparison between items in the xs array, due to the possibility of them being of differing types.

The error being returned is:

```
No instance for (Eq a) arising from a use of ‘==’
Possible fix:
  add (Eq a) to the context of
    the type signature for myCompare :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> Int
```

I'm new to types, and am unsure on how I can cast this - would someone be able to lend me a hand on this?

Comment: Read the error message again. Does it ever says that you are comparing two different types? *No*. It simply says that you have a type signature where you mention type `a` but there is no instance of `Eq a` that can provide the operation `==` in that expression. Learning to read haskell error messages helps *a lot*, so read them carefully when you get one and try to figure out what ghc is trying to do.

Comment: If it helps, the items in a Haskell list always have the same type.

Comment: Also your question isn't about comparing values of different types at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do what the compiler tells you to: add `Eq` constraint to your function.

```
myCompare :: Eq a => Int -> Int -> [a] -> Int
```

When you write `a`, you tell the compiler that the function can operate on any type; in other words, that means you don't expect anything from the type.

Comparing two values of a particular type isn't a given; it's provided by the `Eq` typeclass. While most ADTs can simply derive `Eq` to get that instance, you still need to ensure that the type, values of which you're going to compare, actually *has* that instance, and that's precisely what the constraint is doing.